# How does graphql-ruby connection-based pagination affect ActiveRecord queries?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, graphql

The [graphql-ruby](https://graphql-ruby.org/) gem makes it pretty easy to implement pagination via a GraphQL `Connection`. For example if I add this in my posts query field:

```
module Types
  class QueryType < Types::BaseObject
    field :posts, Types::PostType.connection_type, resolver: Queries::PostsQuery

  end
end
```

... that gives me everything I need to use the cursor-based pagination in my GraphQL queries.

The part I'm not understanding is when I resolve the GraphQL query as below...

```
module Queries
  class PostsQuery < Queries::BaseQuery
    type [Types::PostType], null: false

    def resolve
      posts = Post.all
      puts posts.count
      posts
    end

  end
end
```

...how am I supposed to apply the pagination parameters (`first`, `after`, etc.) to the ActiveRecord query? There doesn't seem to be any obvious reference to them in that overridden `resolve` method.

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out. The answer, for posterity, is that the graphql-ruby gem handles it transparently.

For example, if you execute this query:

```
{
  posts(first:10, after:"Mw") {
    pageInfo {
      startCursor
      endCursor
    }
    edges {
      cursor
      node {
        id
        author
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The graphql-ruby gem alters my existing `posts = Post.all` ActiveRecord call by adding the LIMIT and OFFSET to it behind the scenes:

```
  Parameters: {"query"=>"{\n  posts(first:10, after:\"Mw\") {\n    pageInfo {\n      startCursor\n      endCursor\n    }\n    edges {\n      cursor\n      node {\n        id\n        author\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}", "variables"=>nil, "graphql"=>{"query"=>"{\n  posts(first:10, after:\"Mw\") {\n    pageInfo {\n      startCursor\n      endCursor\n    }\n    edges {\n      cursor\n      node {\n        id\n        author\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}", "variables"=>nil}}
   (0.2ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "posts"
  ↳ app/graphql/queries/posts_query.rb:8:in `resolve'
20
  Post Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" LIMIT ? OFFSET ?  [["LIMIT", 10], ["OFFSET", 3]]
  ↳ app/controllers/graphql_controller.rb:15:in `execute'
Completed 200 OK in 10ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms | Allocations: 4947)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to pass it as an argument like first, last, before, after etc...

try to run your query like this and see if you're getting the results.

```
query {
  PostsQuery(first: 5){
    pageInfo{
      endCursor
      startCursor
      hasPreviousPage
      hasNextPage
    }
    edge{
      cursor
      node{
        id
        title
        content
        published
      }
    }
  }
}

OR

query {
  PostsQuery(first: 5, after: "ABC"){
    edge{
      cursor
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Asmita. Your suggestion about adding `PostsQuery(first: 5, after: "ABC"){` makes complete sense; I was more wondering what happens downstream of that, in the Ruby code that resolves the GraphQL query